# CROSS COMPILE:arm-eabi-gcc -static -o hello hello.c

Tags: arm, embedded-linux, cross-compiling

**while cross compiling (application)"arm-eabi-gcc -static -o hello hello.c" following error occurring**

```
hello.c:1:18: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
hello.c:2:19: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
hello.c:3:19: error: string.h: No such file or directory
hello.c:4:19: error: fcntl.h: No such file or directory
hello.c:5:20: error: unistd.h: No such file or directory
hello.c:6:23: error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
hello.c:7:22: error: sys/stat.h: No such file or directory
hello.c:8:23: error: sys/ioctl.h: No such file or directory
```

`
I am able to cross compile kernel modules.

Comment: If this will compile with your host compiler (rather than cross compiler) it would appear tou appear to have a broken cross compiler installation, or at the very least your include paths are not set.  Another possibility is that your source file is faulty in that you mistakenly specified all of these system includes with quotes rather than angle brackets.

Comment: Quotation marks should work fine for system include files, too.

Comment: i think the cross compile will not find these head files in your system PATH, which for normal `gcc` compiler. cross compiler should have it own PATH maybe

Answer (score 1):

if you try to cross-compile user program in linux machine, you shoud use not `arm-eabi-gcc` but `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`.

Comment: Yes, arm-eabi-gcc is a bare metal toolchain: it has no libc. Thus, the C headers and library are missing and EnterKEY cannot compile a user space program.

Answer (score 0):

you have a broken crosscompiler. Get a better toolchain, you have a lot of options:

- [OpenEmbedded](http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Main_Page)
- [Yocto](https://www.yoctoproject.org/)
- [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/)
- [Scratchbox](http://www.scratchbox.org/)